# How to go back to the previous activity on single click and for twice click how to exit application?

Tags: android, navigation, fragment

When i click back button single time then it will move to the previous screen and when i click twice it will exit my application.

I tried alot and refer stackoverflow questions too but can't solving my problem so that i put a question here.

**NAvigation.java**

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    else {

        backButtonHandler();
        //   Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


public void backButtonHandler() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Navigation.this);
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Leave application?");
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave the application?");
    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.m_visit);
    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

i tried this way but this is only help me for exit the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this logic

```
private int clickCount = 0;
private long delay = 100;
Timer timer = new Timer();
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (clickCount == 2) {
    timer.cancel();
    //operations to be performed on double click
  } else {
    clickCount++;
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override public void run() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override public void run() {
            clickCount = 0;
            //operations to be performed on single click
          }
        });
      }
    }, delay);
  }
}
```

Set whatever delay you want between click in `delay` field

Comment: its not working.. when i pressed single tym back button then the dailog is display but i want to show that dailog in twice click

Comment: the code I have added is just a sample. the `if` block will be executed when the user double-clicks back button and `else` block's `run()` method will be executed on single click. so add whatever operation you want on single click and double click.